# Styling a input's background color and removing the disabled red circle when hovering over it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to remove the red circle when hovering over a disabled input. I'm using bootstrap's form-control and when disabled it shows a red circle when I hover over it. Can I remove this red circle? Can I change the background color of the input?

Tried both in this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zxnw8245/4/), but didn't have any luck.

```css
.bcolor {
    background-color: "#fffff;"
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">Home</span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control bcolor" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" disabled>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.form-control[disabled] {
 cursor: auto;
}
```

If you feel like you want a custom cursor then w3schools has the [answer](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto)

Comment: thanks.what about changing the color of the disabled input to something like white?

Comment: @user1186050 then it would not appear very disabled, would it? Perhaps you want a `readonly` input

Comment: I still want the color changed to something like white. I will have text inserted into it, but it will be disabled. I have an event onclick for it to show a different element.

Comment: There you go: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url(smiley.gif),url(myBall.cur),auto

Comment: you cant attach onclick event to disabled items, make it readonly then

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue here is that your background color property you are setting has invalid syntax.

```
background-color: "#xxxxxx;"
```

This should not have quotes.

---

Your second problem is CSS specificity. You may want to read up on that. Either way, this can be solved by making your rule more specific, by adding the containers, and the attributes to your rule, like `[disabled]`, or you can take the easy way out and use the `!important` clause.

```
background-color: #xxxxxx !important;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxnw8245/5/)

Comment: what about changing the color of the text to black?

Comment: add `color: black` to that rule.

Answer (score 0):

This would remove the red circle.

```
.bcolor{cursor: text;background-color: #72A4D2!important;}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bootstrap class which is setting cursor style.

```
.form-control[disabled], fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

You can change cursor style by modifying class value.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background of disabled input filed us this in your CSS:

```
input[type="text"]:disabled{background-color:white;}
```

To remove the special mouse use something like this, like odedta already said:

```
.form-control[disabled] {
 cursor: auto;
}
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxnw8245/6/)

I made an edit on the fiddle, there were the wrong version of the changes in it. Please accept one of the answers you are using.